# Use correct variable from scope in onFirstInteractive

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

So I am trying to send in information when using the `onFirstInteractive` callback.

Here is what i am trying to do.

```js
function initViz() {
    var views = viz.getWorkbook().getPublishedSheetsInfo();
    for(var v = 0; v < views.length;v++) {
        var name = views[v].getName();
        var options = { hideTabs: true, hideToolbar: true, 
            onFirstInteractive: function() { 
                console.log("Viz has finished loading >" + name);
                getFilters(name);
            }
        };
        var url = views[v].getUrl();
        url = url.replace("/#/site/", "/t/");
        var containerDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
        document.body.appendChild(containerDiv);
        viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
        viz.hide();
    }
}

function getFilters(name) {
    console.log(name);
}
```

But it seems that every time `getFilters` is called, `name` is always the "**last** views" name.

How can I get the correct `name` value when the `options` object is created?

Answer (score 0):

Change function to an Inline closure

```js
function initViz() {
    var views = viz.getWorkbook().getPublishedSheetsInfo();
    for(var v = 0; v < views.length;v++) {
        var name = views[v].getName();
        var options = { hideTabs: true, hideToolbar: true, 
            onFirstInteractive: (function(name) { 
                return function() { 
                    console.log("Viz has finished loading >" + name);
                    getFilters(name);
                }
            })(name)
        };
        var url = views[v].getUrl();
        url = url.replace("/#/site/", "/t/");
        var containerDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
        document.body.appendChild(containerDiv);
        viz = new tableau.Viz(containerDiv, url, options);
        viz.hide();
    }
}

function getFilters(name) {
    console.log(name);
}
```

Sources

[JavaScript Callbacks Variable Scope Problem](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/javascript-callbacks-variable-scope-problem)

[Understanding closures, callbacks and promises in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/amysimmons/3d228a9a57e30ec13ab1)